# Add OpenCV(Both Java & Native) + Tesseract in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface, tesseract

I want to integrate Tesseract in my android studio project. In the project I already have integrated the opencv(on java and native side). I am doing processing using java-side opencv and native-side opencv too. Until now my code is running perfect but now i wanted to integrate Tesseract in the same project but now app crashes after installing on phone. I have followed these tutorials to add tesseract as library https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/840623/Android-Character-Recognition this also.
My wild guess is error is due to the build.gradle file i have created in tess-two library folder because there is no liblept.so and libtess.so present in app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi folder.

Build.gradle in tess-two library is taken from link and build.gradle in project root directory isPlease help.